# What are the default listeners in TestNG, and where do I find this list?

Tags: java, listener, testng

I was curious to know what the default listeners are in TestNG. I saw a bool property on the Ant task for useDefaultListeners but I would like to know what these are and where I can find them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are four default reporters:

http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/org/testng/reporters/SuiteHTMLReporter.java

The main reporter that creates the HTML reports.

http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/org/testng/reporters/FailedReporter.java

This reporter creates testng-failed.xml

http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/org/testng/reporters/XMLReporter.java

This reporter generates an XML file that captures the entire description of this test run. This XML file is used by other tools for further generation (PDF, etc...).

http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter.java

This reporter creates a file that is suitable to be emailed either attached or inline.

Hope this helps.

-- 
Cedric

Answer (score 5):

These seem to change every so often. The answer seems to be to look in the source code -
[initializeDefaultListeners()](http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#770)

```
private void initializeDefaultListeners() {
  m_testListeners.add(new ExitCodeListener(this));
  if (m_useDefaultListeners) {
    addReporter(SuiteHTMLReporter.class);
    addReporter(FailedReporter.class);
    addReporter(XMLReporter.class);
    addReporter(EmailableReporter.class);
    addReporter(JUnitReportReporter.class);
  }
}
```

When I experimented with altering this (to remove `SuiteHTMLReporter`), it was important to retain the difference between listeners and reporters, and to retain the order of the reporters.

Answer (score 2):

There is (at least) one quite useful reporter missing:

- org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter

The reporter creates the suitename/suitename.html which is linked in the html reporter result at the "results" link on the left side.

Comment: One quick note: If you use this listener it is very likely to generate boatloads of (uncompressed) data, so be aware.